# How do I setup my ubuntu on a WiFi network?

Tags: wireless

I need to set up Ubuntu for WiFi network.  How do I do that?  I cannot see the name of my network listed.

Comment: Do other networks show up?  If so, are you sure your network is advertising itself?

Comment: Please add some hardware information to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 4):

**You need to check for additional drivers , to install the appropriate driver for you wifi:**

If you are using 11.04: 
Open the dash --> Additional drivers

and activate the driver.

[image]

**Note:** You may need to be connected to a wired network first.

see : [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-proprietary-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the name (essid) of the wireless network and is there a password key protecting it?  If you know this information you can manually enter the information in to the network manager.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +_+ my... that theme is... indescribable...
I almost downvoted D:! Promise me no children were harmed or kittens killed in the application of that theme! Please!

Comment: It's good to know that you almost downvoted based on just my theme... and since you have appointed yourself the fashion police please throw out some recommendations as well along with your snarky comments.

Comment: that's no way to respond to a joke. I didn't vote at all, because I'm out of votes :). Who ever downvoted, must have their own reason... btw you might want to check the chat room - I'm not the only one who found the theme... interesting ;).

Comment: @ Roland Taylor: I didn't say you downvoted (i did reference your "almost")... my answer wasn't that good and I understand that... and I'm sure you found my theme interesting and that's why I have it up right now, cause I'm not seeing anything better out there and I like the visuals of light background and dark font... that's why I said if you have any suggestions I'll hear it..

Comment: Whoever voted this answer down probably did it because it uses KDE programs and the asker isn't using KDE.